# Using Hive metastore for client application performance

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to hadoop. Please help me in below concept.
It is always good practice to use hive metastore(into other db like mysql etc) for production purpose.
What is the exact role and need of storing meatadata on RDBMS ?
If we create a client application to get hive data on UI, will this metadata store help to improve the performance to get data?
If yes What will be the architecture of this kind of client application? Will it hit first RDBMS metastore ? How it will be different form querying hive  directly in some other way like using thrift?

Hadoop experts ,please help

Thanks

Comment: check this article about hive, it may help [link](http://elsoufy.blogspot.com/2014/09/getting-started-with-hive.html)

Comment: metastore is already in mysql and I wanted to take advantage of RDBMS metadata (mysql) in client application.What will be data flow for to get data in client application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prestodb](http://prestodb.io/) that allows you to run/translate SQL queries against HIVE. It has a [mysql connector](http://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/mysql.html) that you can use to exploit your stored hive schema.

Thus from your client application, you just need a [JDBC driver](http://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/jdbc.html) as any RDBMS out there.